# Responsive website is not really responsive

Tags: responsive

I have just started with web developing and made a simple header of the website with logo and navbar. The thing is that the website should be responsive and change the layout (resizing  it to 580px) displaying menu in two columns but it doesn't. The same when the website is fully extended there should be menu displayed in one line but it is messed as well. Can you have a look at code and tell me what is wrong ?

Here you go:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lange="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Painting with responsive menu</title>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel = "stylesheet"
   type = "text/css"
   href = "stylesheet6.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/paintinglogo.png"></a>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body> 

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1220px;
    width: 98%;
    background-color: #2F3038;
    padding: 2%;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
header{
    width: 98%;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
    text-align: center;
}
img{
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
nav {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;   

}
nav ul li a {
    background-color: #737373;
    border: 1px solid #2F3038;
    color: #2F3038;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font: 16px, Arial, Helvitica;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 16.5%;

    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: background 0.5s ease;
    transition: background 0.5s ease;
}
nav li a:hover{
    background: #DADADA;
}

/*-------------------Media Queries------------*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 580px){
    nav li a{
        width: 50%;
        font: 13px Arial, Helvitica;
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #2F3038;

    }
    nav li:nth-child(even) a{
        border-right: none;
    }
}
```

Thanks Guys !

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of mistakes:

- not using `box-sizing: border-box` gives you wrong width calculation for `nav ul li a` because the width **16.5%** does not include paddings and thus forces a wrap
- you are using the wrong tool (floats) - better use Flexbox with wrapping

---

```
  *
  {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
   .wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1220px;
    width: 98%;
    background-color: #2F3038;
    padding: 2%;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
  header{
    width: 98%;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  img{
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
  }
  nav {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;   
    padding-left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
nav ul li
{
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: block;
}
nav ul li a {
    background-color: #737373;
    border: 1px solid #2F3038;
    color: #2F3038;
    display: block;
    font: 16px, Arial, Helvitica;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;

    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: background 0.5s ease;
    transition: background 0.5s ease;
}
nav li a:hover{
    background: #DADADA;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 580px){
    nav ul li
    {
      flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    }
    nav li a{
        font: 13px Arial, Helvitica;
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #2F3038;

    }
    nav li:nth-child(even) a{
        border-right: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 325px){
    nav ul li
    {
      flex: 0 0 50%;
    }
}
```